# CMake - Generating Visual Studio project using Intel Compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake, intel

Is there a simple (or hack) way to generate a Visual Studio 2008 project that uses Intel Compiler from cmake?

I have found some [notes](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-February/027208.html) about using `ICProjConvert`. Does anyone have any scripts or CMake snippets that are proven to work?

Here's the screenshot of the final solution I'd like to obtain. Note that it contains Intel Compiler projects:
[alt text http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/370/screenau.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/370/screenau.png)

Comment: I can do it in Visual Studio itself with just one click, but would prefer to have a ready project out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The situation is not that good at the moment. After much googling, I've managed to find the following [thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg29092.html) on the mailing list. It turns out that I'm not the only one struggling with the problem.</strike>

For the time being there is no easy solution, as:

- cmake does not have a generator that would give the result out of the box
- it seems that there is currently no way to do post-generate tasks with cmake

As a quick fix I can do the following:

- generate the VS solution and then use the one-click Intel Conversion tool (automatisation gone)
- write some shell scripts to do the conversion - a bit ugly

**Update:**
Doing the project conversion in the post-generate task is a bit of a hack. I started to think about modifying the existing Visual Studio generator(s) to be able to create the right structure. The structure itself does not differ much from the typical solution:

- New `.icproj` files are introduced between the solution and VS project level. They wrap the VS project and correspond to the blue thingy on the screenshot.
- Original `.vcproj` remain unchanged. They are being referenced (by GUID and name) in the `.icproj` files
- Unique references to `.vcproj` files in the solution `.sln` definition are replaced with the references to `.icproj` files. The project type is changed as well to a Intel Project specific constant GUID.

**Update 2:** Check the [bug tracker](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=6929).