# cmake with Intel compiler set as platform toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I have the Intel compiler platform install on my development machine, when using Cmake to generate a visual studio 2010 solution, I want to be able to specify the platform toolset to be using "Intel" instead of "vc100".

I cant seem to find the setting to change this, when I change the compiler to icl the solution still builds with the vc100 compiler until I manually change the platform toolset.

Comment: Here the link on exact question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984121/cmake-generating-visual-studio-project-using-intel-compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for similar functionality as well, for setting the Windows SDK 7.1 as the default toolset for a large number of projects, without having to go through and change each one by hand.

I believe that the CMAKE people have added that functionality, and you can use something like:

```
set_target_properties(${YOUR TARGET} PROPERTIES PLATFORM_TOOLSET "Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.1")
```

Have a look at:

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12876

for details of the change.

Comment: I tried this with CMake 2.8.10.2 and the toolset "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)", and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to change the platform toolset by using a command-line option (CMake 3.2):

```
cmake . -G "Visual Studio 12" -T "LLVM-vs2013"
```